# Spurious "<function> is expected to return a value" warning?

Tags: c++, warnings, solaris, sunstudio

I'm working under Sun Studio 12.3 on SunOS 5.11 (Solaris 11.3). Its providing a spurious warning:

> "<file.h>", line 1: Warning: "<function>" is expected to return a value.

The function is part of a base class interface and looks like so. I only mention the base class interface to avoid the "why would you do that" discussions. A non-member function like below is enough to trigger it.

```
int foo()
{
    throw runtime_error("Not implemented");
}
```

I found mention of similar problems. For example, the [Xapian-core](https://xapian.org/docs/xapian-core-1.2.23/NEWS) change log states:

> - Disable " is expected to return a value" warning from Sun's C++
>     compiler, as it fires for functions ending in a "throw" statement.  Genuine
>     instances will be caught by compilers with superior warning machinery.

According to [SunStudio C++ compiler pragma to disable warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1106898/608639), I can use `-erroff=voidretw`. I'm concerned about `-erroff=voidretw` because it might suppress valid findings. Also, if I go with the `#pragma`, then I need to push and pop it to avoid cross pollinating into user code. I don't know how to push and pop warning states under Sun Studio.

My question is, how do I disable the warning for the one function in the header under Sun Studio?

---

This looks like a duplicate even though the message is different: [How to silence 'The last statement should return a value' warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5637561/608639) I think I am going to vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: If you can modify that function, you could just add a `return 0;` after the `throw`. Of course, then other compilers will probably warn about unreachable code, so you'll need to surround it with some Sun Studio specific `#ifdef`

Comment: If dont need to return anything and simply raise exception why not you change the method to void foo().

Comment: @sagar - Its an interface. Derived classes will return a value.

Comment: Given the [C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) states "a return statement with any other operand **shall be used** only in a function whose return type is not `cv` void", that "Genuine instances will be caught by compilers with superior warning machinery." statement comes across as parochial, arrogantly close-minded misguided whining from the Xapian developers, literally over being held to a standard.  Since the code doesn't meet the C++ Standard, one could argue an actual error and failure to compile the code could be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++11 you can decorate that function with a noreturn attribute:

```
[[noreturn]] int foo()
{
    throw runtime_error("Not implemented");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sun Studio allows to mark that kind of functions with

```
#pragma does_not_return(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about ?

```
int foo()
{
    return throw runtime_error("Not implemented"), 0;
}
```

Do you get the warning?